# PostgreSQL connection refused. Client presents with public IP address

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have .NET Core application which uses PostgreSQL. When I installed application on a machine which is presented to internet via IP address (Mikrotik via dst-nat), PostgreSQL server refuses connection with information that public IP address can't connect to PostgreSQL server.
But on Mikrotik router, I see that client tries to connect via internal IP address on the server port 5432, but (somehow) presents via public address. PostgreSQL server and client are in different subnets.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a network problem. You should describe that in more detail.

Comment: PostgreSQL reports:
28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<Public IP>", user "<user>", database "<db>", SSL off
When I add my public network to pg_hba.conf, it works. But I see that source IP address is not public IP address, but internal network address of client. Can I specify source IP address of client in NpgSql connection string?

Comment: No, that would be silly. Client: "Hey, in reality I am that IP address which doesn't require a password to connect." Server: "Oh, ok. Then come right in."

Comment: Finally, it was misconfiguration in router config. Thank you for patiance :D